# How can I add new custom field into customer form and then save it into database in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, extensions, customer, custom

I am using `magento version 1.9.1.0`, I want to add new custom field into customer form and then save this new field into database. And Again on form edit I want to back this filed on customer form.

In magento customer form(in admin panel) I want to pass a new field value as hidden field. And when I save this customer form, my new field will be save into database and on editing customer form want this new field back into form for editing purpose.

Please suggest me, I look some off the `PHP` file in folder `/STA/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/`, But I did not get the way where I add my custom `PHP` code to add this new field into database.

My main purpose is that I want to pass an extra field into customer form and then save this new field into database and want to back it on editing the form.

Answer (score 3):

Mukesh,There are no need to work at STA/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model.it is too danger to change to At this place.

There are lot of tutorial in available at magento,Please follow those,it will help you

http://www.danneh.org/2011/07/adding-new-attribute-to-customer-account-in-magento/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426242/how-to-create-new-fields-for-customer

http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-eav-system/

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/

Comment: Many thank Keyul , I want to know  where/how can  I get post data when we submit the customer form. Once I will get that custom filed data I will try to insert this  filed into database from you gave suggestion link.